# My Mikrotik api json_encode shows null data in datatable

Tags: php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Libraries\Mikweb;

class Logs extends Security_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->access_only_admin_or_settings_admin();
    }
    function index() {
    
        return $this->template->rander("logs/index");
    }
    //get data for logs list
    function list_data() {      
        $API = new Mikweb();        
        $API->connect('192.168.88.6', 'shyriad', 'shyriad#1332');   
        $list_data = $API->comm('/ppp/profile/print');  
        foreach ($list_data as $data) {
        $result[] = $this->_make_row($data);

        }
        echo json_encode(array("data" => $result));         
        
    }
    
    //prepare an client groups category list row
    private function _make_row($data) {
        return array($data->name);
        
    }   

}

/* End of file logs.php */
/* Location: ./app/controllers/logs.php */
```

Comment: Aside: `rander()` looks like a typo, should be `render()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Your Mikrotik probably has no PPP profiles defined yet - but since you do not initialize the `$result` variable as an empty array, when you try to `json_encode` this variable, its value is NULL.

Comment: My ppp profiles shows data on browser console

Comment: Can you show us `var_dump($list_data)` ?